# Stop a custom.js function

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress

my admin-ajax.php file is causing quite a bit of server load and ending up with a 400 request. Ive honed in on the culprit which appears to be "action=wishlist_counter" caused by woocommerce. Although the cart is disabled its still causing issues. The code in question is found in my themes custom.js file and appears as is below;

```
 /*************************************************************
WOOCOMMERCE  WISHLIST
*************************************************************/

function to_wishlist_count() {
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: to_ajaxurl,
        data: {action : 'wishlist_counter'},
        success:function(data) {
            $('.to-wishlist-number').html(data);
            if(parseInt(data) === 0 ) {
                $('.to-wishlist-counter').animate({top:'-100%'}, 0);
            } else {
                $('.to-wishlist-counter').animate({top:0}, 400);
            }
        }
    });
}

$(document).ready(function() {
    to_wishlist_count();
});

$(document).on('click', '.product-remove a', function() {
    setTimeout(function() { 
        to_wishlist_count();
    }, 1500);
});

$(document).on('click', '.add_to_wishlist', function(){
    var $this = $(this);
    var productAdded = $this.parents('li.product').find('h3').text();
    if (productAdded == '') {
        productAdded = $('h1').text();
    }
    $('.wishlist-notification .item-product').html('"'+productAdded+'"');
    $this.parents('li.product').find('.product-img-wrap div.loading').fadeIn(100);
    setTimeout(function(){
        $('.to-wishlist-number').html(parseInt($('.to-wishlist-number').html())+1);
        $this.parents('li.product').find('.product-img-wrap div.loading').fadeOut(100);
        $('#header .wishlist-notification').fadeIn(400);
        setTimeout(function(){
            to_wishlist_count();
            $('#header .wishlist-notification').fadeOut(400);
        },2250);
    },500);
});

})(jQuery);
```

What would be the best way of removing this code or ceasing it from its dastardly activities. Removing it from the file? or perhaps a function of sorts?